# What changes i need to do on my old php script to work with new msqli or pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I Have Try To Modify My Script Now The Script Have No Error´s but wen i call by ajax in to the file http://villageop/saveid.php?user_id=100
its look like the script have work well but it do nothing on database it have not modify The Database

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "publiadd_publix";
$password = "1a3g7893fsh";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=publiadd_registervillageop", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


if(isset($_GET['user_id'])){
//$user_id = intval($_GET['user_id']);
     //Lightly sanitize the GET's to prevent SQL injections and possible XSS attacks

    $sql = "INSERT `publiadd_registervillageop`   
      //(`user_id`) 
      //VALUES ('publiadd_registervillageop');
      //";

    //$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `publiadd_registervillageop`.`users` (`user_id`) VALUES ('user_id');");
    //$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_id = SET user_id +'$user_id' WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);



     if($sql){

          //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
          echo 'Your ID was saved. Congrats!';

     }else{

          //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
          echo 'There was a problem saving your points. Please try again later.';

     }

}else{
     echo 'Your id wasnt passed in the request.';
}

// close MySQL connection 
$conn = null;
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can't mix MySQL APIs. Consult the duplicate link the question was closed with.

Comment: And It Give Me Connected successfullyYour ID was saved. Congrats!